# How to get data of RecyclerView items that is not shown on Screen?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView that each item of it contain a question title and also a recyclerView inside it. I want to change the color of items inside the second recyclerView when clicking on a send button. I do this with these lines of code:
(`questionListView` is the RecyclerView and `ansRecycle` is second RecyclerView)

```
        for (int i=0;i<adapter.getItemCount();i++){
            questionListView.scrollToPosition(i);
            questionListView.
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
            View view=questionListView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).itemView;
            RecyclerView ansRecycle=view.findViewById(R.id.checkedAnswerLayout);
            for(int j=0;j<ansRecycle.getAdapter().getItemCount();j++) {
                View temp=ansRecycle.getChildAt(j);
                CheckBox ch=temp.findViewById(R.id.checkedChoice);
                if(ch.getText().toString().equals(questions.get(i).getCorrectAnswers())){
                    ch.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }

        }
```

For items that are shown on screen all things are fine but for others, there is no existence ViewHolder and I can not change the color of them.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around solution would be:

1. add a field to the Question - like int color = your color with setters/getters
2. on click get the questionItem and set the color of it to a new color
3. onBind of the recyclerView's find the textView and set the color based on your queston
4. same with answers.

for example

```
 holder.textView.setColor(question.getColor());
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I want. And I think another solution is to set a static variable. When the button is clicked change the value of the variable and also we should check this variable in onBind, if it's set to for example "1" change the color of textbox else we do nothing

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that items that are not on screen doesn't exist. The whole point of recyclerview is that it uses small amount of views, and recycle them when they leave the screen.
What you should do is do the same "if" when you bind the data.:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyDataViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(ch.getText().toString().equals(questions.get(i).getCorrectAnswers())){
            ch.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
```

Comment: but I want to change color when a button is clicked. If I write this "if" when the user is scrolling on the screen and also button is not clicked , the color of checkbox changed.